# Factor group computations

Tags: group-theory

Continuing my independent study of Fraleigh (See my other posts which the users of this forum have been very helpful in answering).

Section 15 on Factor Group Computations.

I'm confused about Example 15.2

It reads (I still don't understand Latex, something I need to learn, and hopefully will learn soon): Compute Z/{0}

The solutions says: N = {0} has only one element, so every coset of N has only one element. That is, the cosets are of the form {m} for m an element of Z. There is no collapsing at all, and consequently, Z/{0} is isomorphic to Z.

I'm confused about what they mean by "There is no collapsing at all". Surely, it is true that for any m in Z, m is collapsed to the coset {m} of Z/{0}.

I'm not exactly sure what context they are using by the term collapse.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of vague language, but 'collapsing' would mean that you can have distinct elements in your original group representing the same coset. But here, $[m] = [n]$ iff $m-n \in \{0\}$. i.e., $m-n =0$.

(Where $[m]$ denotes the class of $m$ in the quotient, i.e., the coset $m+\{0\}$).

An example of 'collapsing' would be taking the subgroup $5\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$. Then in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, $[m]=[n]$ iff $m \equiv n\; (\textrm{mod}\; 5)$, so all integers that are congruent modulo 5 collapse to the same class in the quotient.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree completely. But, according to that definition, in this particular example that I cited, and any example for that matter, [m] = [m] for any m in Z, since m - m is in {0}. So, we'd say "m is collapsed to {m} for all m in Z". But, they say "No collapsing". Do they simply mean, "no two distinct elements are collapsed to the same coset"?

Comment: Indeed. See my edit. I suppose you can think of it in the sense that you're not losing any information about the original group, and this is of course the case whenever you factor out the trivial group.